# Touching in UIScrollview?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using `ScrollviewDelegate` Protocol in viewcontroller, but I am using Custom 
`UIView(UIImageview)` in that custom view.

For some reason, `touchMoved` is not being called. Does anyone have any ideas why this is (not) happening?

Answer (score 7):

If scrolling in UIScrollView is enabled then `touchMoved` events are not propagated to the scroll view contents. How to workaround that depends on what you want to achieve. In my application I needed just to drag an object inside `UIScrollView` and I did the following in contentsView touch handlers for that:

1. In touchesBegan: event I checked if I tapped object to be dragged. If YES - then disabled scrolling in UIScrollView
2. Then as scrolling was disabled my contents view started to receive `touchesMoved` event and I could "drag" my object there.
3. In `touchesEnded:` I reenabled scrolling.

If you want something more complex you can subclass UIScrollView and try to override its touch handlers (see also `hitTest:withEvent:` method)